# AliasMatch regex syntax

Tags: regex, alias, vhosts

Can someone point me towards why this AliasMatch regex isn't working (throwing a 404, not server error):

```
AliasMatch (?i)^/scripts/(\w+)/admin/(\w+).js \cms\modules\$1\scripts\admin\$2.js
```

I am trying to match:

```
/scripts/analytics/admin/index.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to swap the backslashes for forward slashes (Windows)

```
AliasMatch ^/scripts/(\w+)/admin/(\w+)\.js /cms/modules/$1/scripts/admin/$2.js
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to escape the `.`. Try this

```
AliasMatch (?i)^/scripts/(\w+)/admin/(\w+)\.js \cms\modules\$1\scripts\admin\$2.js
```

Comment: @Ashley good that you found your problem, my next suggestion would have been to add other tags to your question, like "Apache", because I found this only because of "regex" and I assume the specialists for this problem hasn't seen this question.